# Weird goings on with SB_THUMBTRACK and listbox

Tags: winapi, mfc, listbox

I have an owner drawn listbox (CListBox in MFC) with 100,001 items in it.  The listbox is single column with a vertical scrollbar.  There is nothing else special about it as far as I can see.  The styles are:

```
LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | LBS_EXTENDEDSEL | LBS_NODATA | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
```

I have my own data structure behind it and instead of inserting the items one by one, I just perform a pBlistBox->SendMessage(LB_SETCOUNT, 100000, 0) to set the count of items in the listbox.

My issue is that when I scroll down the listbox by grabbing the thumb on the scrollbar, when it gets near 65000+ (can't see if it's exactly 65535, but I expect it is), it then sort of wraps around back to 0.  The items that are drawn from WM_DRAWITEM are wrong.  When I should be near 70,000, then items are near 4,500 or so.  If I drag all the way to the bottom and let go, the thumb bounces back to 34,454 or so.  It looks to be some kind of limit.  However, if I hit HOME or END keys it does the right thing.  If I use the scroll arrows, it also does the right thing.  If I click in the page down areas it also does the right thing.  The only time it does not do the right thing is when it scrolls via the thumb (SB_THUMBTRACK).

Anyone have any ideas how I can get it to scroll correctly?  Obviously it seems to be some kind of 16-bit limit, but GetScrollInfo() shows that it knows to scroll the full amount.

Comment: This is [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/580139/292432).

Comment: The WM_VSCROLL message reports the position in a WORD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get full control of the scrol bar you. Need to call GetScrollInfo or GetScrollPos

The behaviour is fully documented in the [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787585(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer. I fixed this earlier today. arx's and Hans's comments pointed me in the right direction.  There is still some mystery about it, because I was able to create a simple example where it worked calling the default wndproc. My listbox in my main program with lots of cruft had the problem, and using Get/SetScrollInfo in WM_VSCROLL handler solved the problem.